# groovy - duplicate name for field and property

Tags: groovy

I am trying to understand the below point in the [codehaus page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans) under 'Properties and field rules' section.

- You can declare a property and a field of the same name, the property will use that field then.

Does that mean we could have two variables one private and other public and the private uses the public field? Please see below sample program I tried for my understanding.

```
class Car {
    private def brake
    def brake // when does this get used? if I declare public, it gives compilation error

    protected void setBrake() {
        this.brake = brake
    }       

    static def main(args) {
        Car c = new Car()
        c.setBrake 'abc'    
        println c.brake
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what it means.

```
class Car {
    private def brake

    // Same name property will add getter/setter for the above field
    def brake

    static def main(args) {
        Car c = new Car()
        c.setBrake 'abc' // Use setter   
        println c.getBrake() // Use getter
    }   
}
```

Try above sample commenting out the property, you should see `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException` for `setBrake()`, because it gets added by the property.

The verbiage in the page says that if you have a field (may be private) and a property ( def brake) then the property will add the accessor methods for that field instead of creating a new private field.